# modal with bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog

I need your help solving a problem ...

I'm new to vue and I can't use modal bootstrap-vue.

I need to load a form with the data into my "MODAL" so that I can change it, but I can't load this data by the user ID inside the modal form.

```
        <PageTitle icon="fa fa-cogs" main="Administração" sub="Feriados" />
        <b-table hover striped :items="feriados" :fields="fields" small class="mt-0 mb-0">
            <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
                <b-button variant="warning" @click="loadFeriado(data.item)" class="mr-2" size="sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </b-button>
                <b-button variant="info" @click="viewFeriado" class="mr-2" size="sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"> Editar</i>
                </b-button>
            </template>
        </b-table>

        <div>
            <b-modal ref="showFeriado"
                title="Visualizar Feriado"
                size="xl"
                @shown="loadFeriado"
                @hidden="reset"
                @ok="save"
                ok-variant="primary"
                cancel-title="Cancelar">

                <div>
                    <input id="feriado-id" type="hidden" v-model="feriado.id"/>
                    <b-row class="mt-0 mb-0">
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group
                                label="Data do Feriado:"
                                label-for="feriado-data"
                                label-size="sm"
                                class="mt-0 mb-0">                        
                                <v-date-picker v-model="feriado.data" />
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group label="Nome:" label-for="feriado-descricao" label-size="sm">
                                <b-form-input id="feriado-descricao" type="text"
                                    size="sm"
                                    v-model="feriado.descricao" required
                                    :readonly="mode === 'remove'"
                                    placeholder="Informe o nome do Feriado..." />
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </div>
            </b-modal>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PageTitle from '../template/PageTitle'
import axios from 'axios'
import { baseApiUrl, showError, userKey } from '@/global'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
    name: 'FeriadoAdmin',
    components: {
        PageTitle, 
        moment,
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            mode: 'save',
            feriado: {},
            feriados: [],
            fields: [
                { key: 'id', label: 'Número', sortable: true },
                {
                    key: 'descricao',
                    label: 'Descrição',
                    sortable: true 
                },
                { 
                    key: 'data',
                    label: 'Data',
                    sortable: true,
                    formatter: (value, key, item) => {
                        return moment.utc(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
                    }
                },
                {
                    key: 'actions',
                    label: 'Status'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        viewFeriado () {
            this.$refs.showFeriado.show()
        },
        loadFeriados() {
            axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}/feriados`)
                .then((list) => {
                    this.feriados = list.data
            })
        },
        loadFeriado(feriado) {
            this.feriado = { 
                ...feriado,
                data: moment.utc(feriado.data).toDate()
            }
            //console.log(feriado)
        }
     },
    mounted() {
        this.loadFeriados()
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This console error occurs when attempting to load data into the modal form:

[image]

Comment: It appears from the error you are calling `.data` on a value of `undefined`. This could be happening because the request to generate the object returns a null/undefined value, or perhaps you are trying to render this component before the data is available. In `loadFeriado` I see that you use `feriado.data` however you don't show what the value of feriado is.

Comment: @rob I just need to load data from a given table id into the modal form.